# jQuery : Select all Select Element with value selected only to send in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to Improve my ajax request speed so my ajax code is like this

```
$.ajax({
    url:url_option,
    type:'POST',
    dataType:'json',
    data:$('#product input[type=\'text\'], #product input[type=\'number\'], #product input[type=\'hidden\'], #product input[type=\'radio\']:checked, #product input[type=\'checkbox\'], #product select, #product textarea, #product input[name=\'quantity\']'),
    success:function(json){

    },
});
```

Because I use it like this `$('#product select')` it picks up all select box is there any way to pick only select elements which are already selected so that I can send only selected select element in ajax request

[image]

I have tried piking many ways like using `has()`, `not()` and using pseudo but not able to find a way to pick only selected Select Element by modifying this: `$('#product select')`

Ex.
I have Three select boxes in this code pen 2 default selected and 1 unselected when I `console.log($('#product select'));` all input inside that div it returns all three 2 selected and 1 unselected but I need to select only that Two Select Element which is selected

```js
console.log($('#product select')); // is there any way to pick only 2 selected select element
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="product">
    <div class="form-select-group form-group required">
        <label class="control-label" for="input-option28521">HDD/SSD OPTION:</label>
        <select name="option[28521]" id="input-option28521" class="form-control">
            <option value=""> --- Please Select --- </option>
            <option value="192907" selected="selected">250GB HDD</option>
            <option value="192909">320GB HDD</option>
            <option value="192910">500GB HDD</option>
            <option value="192911">750GB HDD</option>
            <option value="192912">1TB HDD</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-select-group form-group required">
        <label class="control-label" for="input-option28523">Ram:</label>
        <select name="option[28523]" id="input-option28523" class="form-control">
            <option value=""> --- Please Select --- </option>
            <option value="192946">4GB</option>
            <option value="192948">6GB</option>
            <option value="192949">8GB</option>
            <option value="192950">10GB</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-select-group form-group required">
        <label class="control-label" for="input-option28527">Add Antivirus:</label>
        <select name="option[28527]" id="input-option28527" class="form-control">
            <option value=""> --- Please Select --- </option>
            <option value="192968" selected="selected">Leave Me Unprotected</option>
            <option value="192970">Install QuickHeal Antivirus 1-Year License (+₦2,500) Renewable</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

if anyone knows or is there any way that already posted in SE please point me to that post
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.filter()`, to return those selects which have a value:

```
$('#product select').filter(function(){ return $(this).val().length })
```

```js
$(() => {
  console.log($('#product select').filter(function(){ return $(this).val().length }).length)
})
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="product">
    <div class="form-select-group form-group required">
        <label class="control-label" for="input-option28521">HDD/SSD OPTION:</label>
        <select name="option[28521]" id="input-option28521" class="form-control">
            <option value=""> --- Please Select --- </option>
            <option value="192907" selected="selected">250GB HDD</option>
            <option value="192909">320GB HDD</option>
            <option value="192910">500GB HDD</option>
            <option value="192911">750GB HDD</option>
            <option value="192912">1TB HDD</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-select-group form-group required">
        <label class="control-label" for="input-option28523">Ram:</label>
        <select name="option[28523]" id="input-option28523" class="form-control">
            <option value=""> --- Please Select --- </option>
            <option value="192946">4GB</option>
            <option value="192948">6GB</option>
            <option value="192949">8GB</option>
            <option value="192950">10GB</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-select-group form-group required">
        <label class="control-label" for="input-option28527">Add Antivirus:</label>
        <select name="option[28527]" id="input-option28527" class="form-control">
            <option value=""> --- Please Select --- </option>
            <option value="192968" selected="selected">Leave Me Unprotected</option>
            <option value="192970">Install QuickHeal Antivirus 1-Year License (+₦2,500) Renewable</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I looking for thank you very much @Anurag Srivastava

Answer (score 0):

Try jquery :selected selector `$('#product option:selected')`. And you can iterate through them to access the values.

```
    $('#product option:selected').each(function() {
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
```

Refer [jquery :selected selector](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) documentation.